# Visual Studio 2013: Mocking Stored Procedures when Unit Testing SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, database-project

I'm experimenting with unit testing of a SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2013.  The output of the stored procedure I want to test is written to a log file by calling another stored procedure, `sp_log`.

It seems to me the easiest way to check whether the stored procedure I want to test is working would be to mock `sp_log` and use a test condition to check the output of the mocked stored procedure.

I could create a mock `sp_log` in the pre-test script, no problem. However, in the post-test script I would like to re-execute the `sp_Log` `CREATE PROC` script to restore it to its original definition. I don't want to cut and paste the `sp_Log CREATE PROC` from the SQL Server Database Project under test as I'm sure the two versions of the `CREATE PROC` (in the SQL Server Database Project and in the Unit Test Project) would get out of sync.

Is there any way I could call the `sp_Log CREATE PROC` script in the SQL Server Database Project from the post-test script in the Unit Test project?

Alternatively, is there any way to record the definition of `sp_log` in the pre-test script then re-run that definition in the post-test script? E.g. is it possible to create a local variable in the pre-test script and read the stored procedure's definition into it, then read the definition back out of the local variable in the post-test script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming `sp_log` in the pre-test script, then rename it back in the post-test script.

**Pre-test:**

```
EXEC sp_rename 'sp_log', 'sp_log_BACKUP'
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_log AS .... /* your mock sp_log */
```

**Post-test**

```
EXEC sp_rename 'sp_log_BACKUP', 'sp_log'
```

I'm not sure of a way to reference the stored procedure definitions in variables or something similar. Hopefully renaming the stored procedure as I have suggested is sufficient.

Comment: Caveat for anyone else thinking of doing this:  If the test fails it appears the post-test script does not run.  So you may be left with a broken database.  I think you'll have to edit the auto-generated .NET test code to ensure the post-test script is run even if a test condition fails.  When a test condition fails it appears to throw an exception, which prevents the remainder of the .NET test code from being executed.

Comment: @SimonTewsi You can fix the code to ensure the post-test script always runs by editing the C# unit test code - you just need to wrap the test action in a try/finally block. This will actually be fixed in an future release of SSDT. See this post on the SSDT forum for a full explanation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e80b77d7-0cdc-4ecf-bd4e-6a03f1d821aa/posttest-not-run-after-test-failed?forum=ssdt

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for that.  It's useful to read Microsoft's suggestions for how to get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm the renaming technique works, in fact I got it demo-ed on a post:

https://tangodude.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/ssdt-database-projects-mocking-database-objects-for-isolated-unit-testing-kind-of/

Sorry for the redundant answer, but don't have enough rep to comment yet. :)

Comment: No need to apologize, I think that's an excellent blog post that adds to the answer already given, by explaining how to get past the problem of cleaning up properly if the test fails.

Comment: BTW: I've noticed that Stackoverflow etiquette seems to favour quoting or paraphrasing the relevant information in your Stackoverflow answer, in addition to adding a link.  That way, if the page being linked to ever changes address or is deleted, the Stackoverflow answer can still stand on its own.  Not sure if it's possible in this case, since you'd probably just end up pasting the whole blog post into your answer, but it might be useful to know in future.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thanks for the advice, I'm still a newbie at SO, so still learning. :)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your database remains in the same state after test execution, I execute it within a transaction. By doing so I do not need to worry about cleaning up the database after test execution. You can find more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833153(v=vs.100).aspx